# Cannot submit the word <script></script> in the textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a problem. when i write the word `<script src=""></script>` in the textarea and submit to display the text, my web server doesn't allow to do that. But i tested it with another web server it worked well. Can you tell me what is the main problem? is it related to web server? how to deal with it? here is the simple code I tested.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
     <textarea name="txt"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" name="btn" />
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
 $text=$_POST['txt'];
 echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure but if [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) is installed, XSS attacks are prevented by default. Check your phpinfo?

Comment: Why do you need to allow this form to submit script tags? [There are countless security issues regarding this.](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/)

Comment: i just want to upload the the script path into database and it's used by admin only.

Comment: @SamSeyma If you only want the script path, why not just put the path in the text area? Are the `<script>` tags really necessary? Also, if you put `@MisterMelancholy` in your response, it'll notify me that you've responded to my comment.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy I also have this idea, but i really want to know why the word <script> wasn't allowed.

Comment: @SamSeyma Fair enough. I was just curious is all. What kind of hosting do you have? What is your server software? Are there any errors being generated as far as you can tell? If you're using shared hosting, it's very possible that a shared hosting company would deny this to protect against XSS since it's the most common hack since SQL injection. And if you're wondering how viable this is, shared hosting services really do these kinds of things. At the place I work as a website developer, our shared hosting company has magic_gpc_quotes enabled regardless of anything I do.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy I used https://lolipopftp.lolipop.jp

Comment: @SamSeyma You should contact their customer support and ask them about it. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy thank you so much for useful information.